# How to set multiple Child Checkbox in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, loops, checkbox

I have a function which is actually i want to use multiple child checkbox in one parent checkBox For Example

```
  [] User Data
     [] create 
     [] delete
     [] update
```

> But using my Code i have i have found something like

```
  [] User Data
  [] create 
  [] delete
  [] update
```

> Adding One after another and so on...

I have Database which design is something like table Name is "**groupFunction**"

```
functionName   functionId   button

 User Data         10        create
 User Data         10        delete
 User Data         10        update
```

> My Code is

```
private void CheckboxListBind()
        {
            //return 1 item since i Have one Item on DB 
            string selFunctionName = "select distinct functionName  from groupFunction where functionId ='10'"; 

            //dt is DataTable which is called in globally 
            dt = dp.getDataTable(selFunctionName, "groupFunction");
            int pCount = dt.Rows.Count;

            if (pCount > 0)
            {
                //FORM_createUser data
                string btnChildCount = "select button from groupFunction where functionId = '10'"; // it return  
                DataTable cdt = new DataTable();
                cdt = dp.getDataTable(btnChildCount, "groupFunction");

                int count = cdt.Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    //FORM_createUser0
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        chkListForm.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["functionName"]);

                        for (int c = 0; c < cdt.Rows.Count; c++)
                        {
                            chkListForm.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["button"]);       
                        }
                    }
                    count--;
                }
                pCount--;
            }

        }
```

Comment: what's you expected result ? i guess checking all child once parent got checked ?

Comment: i want set Parent checkbox(user Data) and it's 3 child button( create , delete, update)  like 3 button will set inside of user Data checkbox